# Cypress AWS S3 List/Upload/Download Objects

Tags: amazon-s3, cypress

I am trying to list objects and if this works later download/upload files to AWS S3. The code below throws an error. What am I doing incorrectly that this doesn't work? I've passed the accessKeyId and accessSecretKey in all possible ways below. I have a config and credentials file on mac and on windows I have just one awscredentials file and also set this on my windows
setx AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1

**CODE**

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    
    function listS3Objects(file, name, type) {
      const s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
        accessSecretKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
        
       // accessKeyId: 'my actual key in credentials file', //aws_access_key_id
       // accessSecretKey: 'my actual secret key in credentials file', //aws_secret_access_key
        region: "ap-southeast-1"
      });
      const params = {
        Bucket: 'testbucketName',
      };
      s3bucket.listObjects(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) { throw err; }
        /* eslint-disable no-console */
        console.log('Success!');
        console.log(data);
        return data;
        /* eslint-enable no-console */
      });
    }
    
    const objs = listS3Objects()
    //Test AWS Credentials
    it('Tests', () => {
      cy.log(objs)
    })
```

**ERROR**

The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

> Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.
node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:400:1
398 |
399 |     function credError(msg, err) {

> 400 |       return new AWS.util.error(err || new Error(), {
> | ^
> 401 |         code: 'CredentialsError',
> 402 |         message: msg,
> 403 |         name: 'CredentialsError'

Answer (score 0):

I'd troubleshoot it this way:

1. Can you run the script to upload or download separately? If not then its with the credentials.
2. if not credentials and this works perfectly can this script be imported into your spec and run? Let the script resolve and return a promise, then use the return value in your spec.

Refer this blog [post](https://sam-nash.medium.com/cypress-and-amazon-web-services-part-1-b3f71432c6cf).

Other options you could consider and cy.exec("aws command goes here")